# Filter Product Collection while Using FPC

Tags: magento2, product-collection, full-page-cache, permissions, magento2.4.6

I'm working on a project right now with about 200k customers that are broken down into 2000 groups. We haven't used customer_group for this because of the large number. But because we have a restricted catalog based on their group, I now have a requirement that requires me to develop something like catalog_permission.

Is there anyone who can recommend the best way to accomplish this?

Magento 2.4.6 cloud edition is being used, and full-page caching is turned on. Please recommend a solution that is compatible with FPC.

Regards

Comment: Magento defaultly use customer_group  for full cache generate

Comment: Yes, but I cannot create 2000 customer_groups because that makes the catalog_permission slow. I need something custom to filter product collections based on custom grouping.

Comment: are you taliking about magento default catalog permission?

Comment: Yes, default catalog permission in cloud edition